# Apache mod_rewrite rule and forever loop

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to rewrite all files that start with "t" from one directory to another directory.

From `/gallery/tXYZ.ext` to `/gallery/thumbnails/thumbs_XYZ.ext`

I have problem with this RewriteRule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^gallery/t(.*)$  /gallery/thumbs/thumbs_$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

because it catches `thumbs` directory again (starts with "t") and forever loop occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is the word `thumbs` also matches `t*` pattern and caused redirection loop.

Use this rule to fix it:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/gallery/thumbs/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^gallery/t(.*)$ /gallery/thumbs/thumbs_$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

OR else:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^gallery/t(?!humbs/)(.*)$ /gallery/thumbs/thumbs_$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```